Pullback of k-algebras
I am trying to show that for 3 reduced and finitely generated ("of finite type") k-algebras R,S and T and maps $\varphi_1: R\to S$ and $\varphi_2: T\to S$, the Pullback $R\times_S T$ exists. I already showed that the underlying set is a reduced algebra and that it satisfies the universal property, but I am stuck at showing that this k-algebra is finitely generated. I found this reference, but it seems to use the fact that the direct product is finitely generated, which to me is not obvious. They also require one of the $\varphi_i$ to be surjective and that S is finite over R. Do I need this assumption?
Edit: I found that it is sufficient for $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ to be surjective.

The assumptions in the stacks project link are important. Even if both $\phi_i$ are finite ring maps you'll have plenty of low-dimensional counterexamples, so you can see that the surjectivity of one of the maps is playing a key role in guaranteeing that the pullback is of finite type.
For simple counterexamples, you might consult this paper of Mondal.  Note that the pullback of two subrings is just their intersection. The author shows that there exist subrings $R_1,R_2$ of $S= \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such  that $S$ is a finite $R_i$-module, $R_i$ is 2-generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, and $R_1 \cap R_2$ is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.
In sum, the category of reduced finite type $k$-algebras certainly does not have pullbacks.

Thanks! I will just restrict myself to the category of finitely generated k-algebras with surjective morphisms
